# Microsoft Authentication Library (msal.js) Multitenant Sign Up Process

Tags: azure, active-directory, multi-tenant, azure-ad-msal, msal.js

I'm trying to set a Single Page Application with Angular having authentication using Azure Active Directory by relying on [MSAL.js](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js). There are details about how to achieve the same with AD v1 in the traditional web app [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/signup).

I've been able to authenticate the user into the system but what I'm struggling to achieve is, sign up the user for the application by registering the tenant details in our application database through a REST API call. I've also given `admin_consent=true` with `extraQueryParameters` and still doesn't seem to make much sense. While giving prompt=admin_consent, it gives the following error since there's already another prompt query parameter, i.e., `prompt=select_account`

[image: error]

The proper way to call with admin consent seems to be as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes#request-the-permissions-from-a-directory-admin) but the MSAL for JS doesn't seem to provide a handle with admin consent.

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The link you're following for implementation looks fine. One possible reason I see is that signup process uses prompt=admin_consent, so the user needs to have enough privileges in relevant AAD to give consent. So try with a user who is in global administrator role for the tenant you're trying to sign up.

In case that still doesn't work out, please share more details on the error message/stack trace you're getting.

Comment: The ideal way in version 2 is to point to adminconsent url by .../common/adminconsent?clientId=..., but there's no option for the same in MSAL for JS so the callBack registered gets invoked as well.